# ConcurrentModificationException while iterating through Vector<EventInjectListener>

Tags: java, android, vector, concurrentmodification

I am getting Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in my code and I am not able to find any proper solution for this. My code is as follows

```
Vector<EventInjectListener> eventInjectListeners = eventsArray.get(eventType);
        if (eventInjectListeners != null) {
            int size = eventInjectListeners.size();
            Iterator<EventInjectListener> it = eventInjectListeners.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                EventInjectListener el = it.next();
                el.eventReceived(eventType,data);
            }
        }
```

The exception is happening inside the while loop. Any suggestions to solve this issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `Vector`, and have you read the documentation for `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: But the way… [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) Javadoc says: "As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, … it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector."